# perl to move outlook emails to another folder

Tags: perl

Hi I have a script that reads thru an email folder and if the subject line starts with 'test' it extracts the mail body to a txt file. I would like it to then move all 6 emails to another folder. but while the script extracts from all 6 emails in the folder, when i add the line `( $message->Move($tofolder);  )` i can only get it to move 3 emails at once, not all of them!
 I get warning: `Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) on ~ /^test /) ..... line`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
  my  $filename = 'c:\\net.txt' ;
   open(FH,"> $filename")
   or die ("cannot open $filename");

my $outlook = Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application')
     or die "Failed Opening Outlook.";

my $namespace = $outlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");
my $folder = $namespace->Folders("test")->Folders("test1");#->Folders; ("Junk Mail")->Folders("Bad");
my $tofolder = $namespace->Folders("test")->Folders("test1");#->Folders; ("Junk Mail")->Folders("Bad");
my $items = $folder->Items;

for my $itemIndex (1..$items->Count)

{
     my $message = $items->item($itemIndex);

   if    ($message->{Subject} =~ /^test/){
     print $message->{Subject}."\n";
     print FH $message->{Body};
      $message->Move($tofolder);


     }

}

close(FH);
```

Comment: Because this is OS specific, we can't reproduce the problem directly. Would you be able to quote the error in more detail? Unintitalised value implies that part of a pattern match is broken. Which line is it on?

Comment: Hi Error is as below, all the emails just have test in the subject line nothing else.                      <code>.                                                                         test
          testtest
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at C:\Users\marshallj\Desktop\
tscripts\n.pl line 35.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at C:\Users\marshallj\Desktop\
tscripts\n.pl line 35.                                           <code>

Comment: Your script is only 34 lines long. What's on line 35 as you're looking at it?

Comment: Sorry it is line 24 ..   if    ($message->{Subject} =~ /^test/){      the first 3 emails are moved ok but the last 2 are not.

Comment: That error message is trying to tell you that either $message is undefined, or $message->{Subject} is undefined when you perform the regex match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what's up - from the comments, an error on line 24 suggests that the thing you're accessing as a message doesn't have a 'Subject' field.

So it might actually not be a message at all.

I've tried something a bit like this (paraphrased a little) which seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
my $filename = 'c:\\net.txt';
open( my $output_fh, ">", $filename ) or die $!;

my $outlook = Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application')
    or die "Failed Opening Outlook.";

my $namespace    = $outlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");
my $archive        = $namespace->GetDefaultFolder(6)->Folders('Archive');
my $deletedItems = $namespace->GetDefaultFolder(3);
my $items        = $archive->Items;

foreach my $msg ( $items->in ) {
    if ( $msg->{Subject} =~ m/^test/ ) {
        print $msg ->{Subject}, "\n";
        print {$output_fh} $msg->{Body};
        $msg->Move($deletedItems);
    }
}

close($output_fh);
```

This moves things from 'Archive' subfolder of 'Inbox' to Deleted Items. And extracts to a file as we go. Note that it just splurges 'body' to the output file, without any separators, so you probably want to do something more complicated. (I've taken to using `$msg -> SaveAs` so I can preserve the whole message object).